# nodejs browser-sync - logging

Tags: node.js, browser-sync

im very new to nodejs but was wondering if the following was easily possible to achieve.

I use Gulp along with browser-sync plugin. I was wondering if there was a way to log every time the browser gets re-injected with the domain and time over a port range. The reason for this being I want to be able to plot productivity over projects without having to manually record this and this seems to be the most logical solution.

Is there anything out there like this or could this easily be added into a Gulp file?

Many thanks, Luke

Comment: What do "browser gets re-injected with the domain and time over a port range" mean?

Comment: sorry, failed english :-) I want to log the domain and time everytime the browser is re-injected with the updated js/css files. (the port range isn't important sorry)

Answer (score 1):

There are some options and you can use the emitter to react to events like stream:changed, browser:reload, client:connected, connection,...

example:

```
var bs = require("browser-sync").create();
bs.init({}); //http://www.browsersync.io/docs/options/
....
bs.emitter.on("file:reload", function(){
console.log("File reload - Details:"+arguments)
});
```